# How to get the second largest number from a list with racket

Tags: racket

As the title says I need help making a function that returns the second largest number from lists. I'm really stuck on this and it's an assignment I need to be done with this Friday. Here is what I got as my best bet but at least part of the problem is that I dont fully understand the procedure maximum. I copied it from another thread in order to try to break it down but I get lost in all the recursions.

```
; I use this to split my list in to two list nested inside a list
(define split-lst
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst) '()
         (list (take lst 2) (drop lst 2))
         )
    )
  )

; This I have not done myself. Dont fully understand how it works.
(define (maximum L)
     (if (null? (cdr L)) 
         (car L) 
         (if (< (car L) (maximum (cdr L)))  
             (maximum (cdr L)) 
             (car L)
         )
    )
)


; Having split my original list using the procedure split-lst above I try to 
;compare the values returned by maximum and return the smallest.
(define next-to?
  (lambda (a-list)
    (split-lst a-list)
     (if (< (maximum (car a-list)) (maximum (cdr a-list)))
         (car a-list)
         (cdr a-list))
    )
  )
```

I get an errormessage from the first line in maximum where it says

```
(if (null(cdr L))      

cdr: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: 1
```

If you could help get it to work I'm gratefull. Just to clarify it does not need to work explicity with maximum or so. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Is there some specific problem you’re running into with your attempts?

Comment: I've edited my question now so hopefully its gives you something to go on. @AlexKnauth

Comment: What is the _Signature_ of the `maximum` function? What are its inputs and outputs supposed to be? Is it a `[Listof Number] -> Number` function?

Comment: It takes a list of numbers as inputt and returns the largest nr in the given list. Was this what you were asking?

Comment: Yes. Now look at all the places where you use `maximum`. Are you always giving it a list of numbers?

Comment: Kinda have to sleep now since it is way to late and it's an early morning tomorrow for me but if you're suggesting thats where the problem migth be I will try to fix it tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: never skip a step. understand `maximum` first.

Comment: Imagine you can only inspect in one drawer at a time, how would you find the second largest value by hand? What is the second largest? If the largest is `10` and there are more with the same value, would the second largest be `10` as well or would it had to be less than the largest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Efficient solution**

Sort list by decreasing order and return second element:

```
(define (2nd-max-num l)
  (second (sort l >)))
```